# How can RemoteWebDriver.FindElementsByCssSelector find an iframe in an iframe?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the method FindElementsByCssSelector like

```
var iframes = RemoteWebDriver.FindElementsByCssSelector("iframe");
```

and that gives me two iframes.

If I write

```
$('iframe');
```

in the browser development console, it displays only one.

In the DOM, one iframe is inside another like:

```
iframe
  html
   body
    form
     div
      table
       tbody
        tr
         td
          iframe
```

Comment: Are you trying to locate them to switch to them or ? If you are just trying to switch to them, you (in general) don't need to locate them first. Just put the locator in the `switchTo()`.

Answer (score 1):

Locate the firs frame and use it to locate the other one

```
IWebElement firstIframe = RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByCssSelector("iframe");
RemoteWebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(firstIframe);
IWebElement secondIframe = iframe.FindElementByCssSelector("iframe");
RemoteWebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(secondIframe);
```

Comment: You probably should just add the one liners to switch to the iframes.

Comment: @JeffC Edited .

Comment: But I mysteriously find both iframes without switching to anything.